# Changes to Site.Master page do not persist for a session

Tags: asp.net

Good Afternoon.

I'm working with the following web pages using ms vwd 2010 express:
    Site.Master/Site.Master.vb, Login.aspx/Login.aspx.vb

The Site.Master has the following:

```
        <div class="loginDisplay">
            <asp:Label ID="WelcomeLabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="LogHyperlink" navigateurl="~/Account/Login.aspx" runat="server">Log In</asp:HyperLink>
        </div>
```

I have the following code in the Login.aspx.vb program:

```
Dim WelcomeLabel As New Label
WelcomeLabel = CType(Master.FindControl("WelcomeLabel"), Label)
WelcomeLabel.Text = "Welcome " & OLEdr.Item("ho1FirstName")

Dim LogHyperlink As New HyperLink
LogHyperlink = CType(Master.FindControl("LogHyperlink"), HyperLink)
LogHyperlink.Text = "Log Out"
LogHyperlink.NavigateUrl = "Exit.aspx"
```

When a user logs in successfully the LogHyperlink is changed from Log In to
Log Out and the WelcomeLabel contains the text "Welcome " and person's first name.  This all works fine.

However, the code only works for the Login.asp page.  When I navigate to another
page, say About.aspx (which also uses the Site.Master), the Site.Master
page is back to the orginal and I have lost the changes the code made.

How can I make the changes persist for the session across all the
web pages?  All the web pages use the Site.Master.

Thank you. 
tfj

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [LoginView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control. It seems you're trying to implement exactly what that control is for. It allows you to display different information depending on whether a user is logged in or not.

Comment: Thank you but I have looked at it and decided not to use it.  I really don't want to take the time to learn all about the Login control.  I will be using my own database for validation and I need to enable/disable menu items.  I haven't worked with a Master Page before.  If what I am trying to do isn't doable please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It is doable ( although I don't recommend it). In Login.aspx.vb add a line to save the user name in session:

```
Session("LoggedInUser") = OLEdr.Item("ho1FirstName").ToString()
Dim WelcomeLabel As New Label
WelcomeLabel = CType(Master.FindControl("WelcomeLabel"), Label)
WelcomeLabel.Text = "Welcome " & OLEdr.Item("ho1FirstName")

Dim LogHyperlink As New HyperLink
LogHyperlink = CType(Master.FindControl("LogHyperlink"), HyperLink)
LogHyperlink.Text = "Log Out"
LogHyperlink.NavigateUrl = "Exit.aspx"
```

In Site.Master.vb load the username from `Session` in Page_Load:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Session("LoggedInUser") Is Nothing Then
        WelcomeLabel.Text = Session("LoggedInUser").ToString()
        LogHyperlink.Text = "Log Out"
        LogHyperlink.NavigateUrl = "Exit.aspx"
    Else
        LogHyperlink.Text = "Log In"
        LogHyperlink.NavigateUrl = "~/Account/Login.aspx"
        WelcomeLabel.Text = ""

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you afzalulh!  Late last night I tried a Session variable much

Comment: Thank you afzalulh!  Late last night I tried a Session variable much like you show in your example and it worked.  I was pretty pleased with myself.  But since you say you don't recommend it I'm concerned.  Could you explain why you don't recommend it?   tfj

Comment: `LiginView` is pretty awesome and its worth spending a bit of time to learn it. The approach above is reinventing the wheel. Hope it makes sense!